# Formatting XML as comma delimited using sed or awk

Tags: xml, awk, sed, grep

I need help formatting this xml file to be imported into a table as comma delimited. I've played around with sed and awk, but it's been a struggle.

Example:

```
<requestID>224</requestID>,
     <ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName </ErrorMessage>,
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>224</requestID><DWLControl></TCRMService>
<requestID>615</requestID>,
    <ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName </ErrorMessage>,
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>224</requestID><DWLControl></TCRMService>
```

Result:

```
 <requestID>224</requestID>,<ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName </ErrorMessage>,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>224</requestID><DWLControl></TCRMService>
 <requestID>615</requestID>,<ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName </ErrorMessage>,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>224</requestID><DWLControl></TCRMService>
```

I've been able to add the commas where I want

```
 sed 's/ErrorMessage>$/ErrorMessage>,/; s/requestID>$/requestID>,/'
```

and I thought it would be better to remove the tabs but it also removes all the spaces.

```
  tr -d ' \t' <grep.xml  > test.xml
```

I'm not sure how to move one line to the end of the previous line...

So this partially works...

```
 awk '{if ($0 ~ /<ErrorMessage>,*/) { printf "%s", $0; getline var; printf "%s\n", var} else {print $0}}' test.xml


    <requestID>260</requestID>,
            <ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName</ErrorMessage>,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>260</requestID></TCRMService>
```

But now I have trouble with moving the ErrorMessage up to the end of RequestID line....

Please note, in the ErrorMessage line, requestID is also in the same line. I think the key is to look for the pattern match on

```
         </requestID>,
```

Comment: Where did request ID 615 come from?

Comment: Sorry, It's suppose to be 615. Each requestID represents a unique record.

Comment: It still says "request control" for ID 224 on both lines.

Comment: This is actually just the sample text from the full xml line. If you'd like I can paste the entire line, but didn't want to overwhelm with too much information.

Comment: No no, a representative excerpt is just fine, but it has to be representative ;) See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
awk -v FS=""  '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",$0);ORS=(NR%3==0?RS:FS)}1' f
```

Comment: wow. This worked. THANK YOU. Going to research and learn what the syntax mean.

Comment: Welcome, you can start your research from here - 
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Answer (score 0):

In awk, very QnD (assuming only spaces, no tabs):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^ +| +$|, *$/,"");printf "%s%s", ($0~/^ *<requestID>/?ORS:","), $0}END{print ""}' file

<requestID>224</requestID>,<ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName </ErrorMessage>,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>224</requestID><DWLControl></TCRMService>
<requestID>224</requestID>,<ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName </ErrorMessage>,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>224</requestID><DWLControl></TCRMService>
```

Now it only need the removal of the leading newline but I need to catch the bus (*can I get a transportation, man*).

Comment: So I tried this and I get the error:

        awk: illegal primary in regular expression ^ +|? +$|, *$ at  +$|, *$
          source line number 1
           context is
     {gsub(/^ +|? +$|, >>>  *$/,"") <<<

Comment: Yes, `?` as the first character in a regexp is ambiguous so some awks will tell you that while others might assume you meant it as a literal. I haven't read the Q so idk what was intended but whatever it is, starting a regexp segment with `?` alone is wrong.

Comment: It was a typo. Made no sense in that context  (trimming: `gsub(/...|? +$|.../)`) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So this partially works...

```
 awk '{if ($0 ~ /<ErrorMessage>,*/) { printf "%s", $0; getline var; printf "%s\n", var} else {print $0}}' test.xml


    <requestID>260</requestID>,
            <ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName</ErrorMessage>,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>260</requestID></TCRMService>
```

But now I have trouble with moving the ErrorMessage up to the end of RequestID line....

Please not, in the ErrorMessage line, requestID is also in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a perl snippet? With bellow new lines are removed, spaces more than two are removed . Commas are not added since your input file as advised in your main question has already the appropriate commas.

```
$ cat file3 |nl
     1  <requestID>224</requestID>,
     2       <ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName </ErrorMessage>,
     3       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>224</requestID><DWLControl></TCRMService>
     4  <requestID>615</requestID>,
     5      <ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName </ErrorMessage>,
     6       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>224</requestID><DWLControl></TCRMService>

$ perl -pe 's/\n//g; s/[[:space:]]{2,}//g; s/<\/TCRMService>/$&\n/g' file3 |nl
     1  <requestID>224</requestID>,<ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName </ErrorMessage>,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>224</requestID><DWLControl></TCRMService>
     2  <requestID>615</requestID>,<ErrorMessage>The following is required: PersonName </ErrorMessage>,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TCRMService xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/schema MDMDomains.xsd"><RequestControl><requestID>224</requestID><DWLControl></TCRMService>
```

Comment: You choose to go with the awk solution , but i would like to know just for my information if this solution worked ok with your real data .